# Get access token from OpenID Connect

Tags: apex, open-id-connect

I'm trying to use **Keycoak** as `identity provider` for `SSO`.

Following  [salesforce help example](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_provider_openid_connect.htm&language=en_US&type=0)  , I managed to create the login page, redirection, and the user can login succesfulyy , however I wasn't able to obtain access token.

I tried the following inside `AutocreatedRegHandler`  :

```
    string accessToken = Auth.AuthToken.getAccessToken(AuthProviderId, 'Open ID Connect');
    System.debug('accessToken :' + accessToken );
```

but `accessToken`  returns `null` hence `authentication` is not successful.

I also added [Auth provider's scoop](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_provider_addl_params_scope.htm&language=en_US&type=0) but nothing changed.

How to get `access_token` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an `access token` from `Keyclaok` , a `POST` method to `KeyCloak end point` was used, it includes the `client secret`, `client id`, `username` and the `granttype`.

Follow the example below as well as check more info on [KeyCloak's docs](http://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.3/server_development/topics/admin-rest-api.html)

```
public static string getToken(){
    string accessToken='';
    string clientId = 'Your id';
    string clientSecret='Your secret' ;
    string username=UserInfo.getUserName();
    string payload = 'client_id=' + clientId + '&client_secret=' + clientSecret + '&username=' + username + '&grant_type=client_credentials';
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('POST');req.setEndpoint('https://yourdomain/auth/realms/yourrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    req.setHeader('Content-Length',String.valueOf(payload.length()));
    req.setBody(payload);
    Http binding = new Http();
    HttpResponse res = binding.send(req);
    if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
        JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(res.getBody()); 
        while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
            if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && (parser.getText() =='access_token')){
                parser.nextToken();
                accessToken= parser.getText();
            }
        }
    }
    System.debug('accessToken : ' +  accessToken);
    return accessToken;
}
```